# shell script to truncate all MySql tables

Tags: sql, mysql, bash, truncate

I'm looking for a Unix shell script that will truncate all tables in a schema. A similar question was already asked, but I have some additional requirements which makes none of the provided answers satisfactory:

- Must be a Unix shell script (i.e. no python, perl, PHP)
- The script must truncate the tables in an order which respects foreign key constraints
- I'd prefer not to have to use a stored proc

Thanks in advance,
Don

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something cheeky like this:

```
mysqldump  --no-data mydb | mysql mydb
```

Gets a dump of the schema and replays it into the database!

Alternatively, check out [mk-find](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-find.html) in [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/tools.html), you should be able to do something like this:

```
mk-find -exec "truncate %s"
```

Description of mk-find:

> This tool is the MySQL counterpart to
>   the UNIX ‘find’ command. It accepts
>   tests (such as “find all tables larger
>   than 1GB”) and performs actions, such
>   as executing SQL (”DROP TABLE %s”).
>   With this tool at your disposal you
>   can automate many tedious tasks, such
>   as measuring the size of your tables
>   and indexes and saving the data for
>   historical trending, dropping old
>   scratch tables, and much more. It is
>   especially useful in periodic
>   scheduled tasks such as cron jobs.